# Digital logics - logic gates find X

Tags: digital-logic, logic-gates

[image]

find the X output
what I did is this
[image]

I have to find X did I move on the right way the exercise?

Comment: so.. what is the problem?

Comment: Looks correct to me so far. That "someone" could be a bit more specific.

Comment: In addition to writing out the final equation, you may be asked to simplify it by logic minimisation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. You correctly identified the ANDs, ORs, and various NOTs, and the way you wrote the outcomes is the correct notation. You didn't write out the final answer for X so I can't tell you if that's correct, but so far it looks fine.